# Changing text color for inline svg of Bing Maps V8 ajax control

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

In the example here:https://blogs.bing.com/maps/May-2016-(1)/Pushpin-Clustering-in-Bing-Maps-V8. I want to change the white color that shows the count of  the clustered pushpins to something different. Tried the code below but it didn't work. Is there another way to change it?

```
cluster.setOptions({
            icon: svgString,
            anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(radius, radius),
            textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, radius - 8),
            color: Microsoft.Maps.Color.fromHex('#111111') 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color pushpin option changes the color of the default pushpin. There is no option to change the color of the text value, but since you are using inline SVG, this is easy enough to do right in your inline SVG. You can include the "{color}" placeholder in your SVG and it will be replaced by the color you specify in the pushpin color option. Here is an example:

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30"><circle cx="15" cy="15" r="13" style="stroke:orange;stroke-width:2;fill:yellow;"/><text x="10" y="20" style="fill:{color};">{text}</text></svg>';

var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), { 
    icon: svg.replace('{text}', 'hi'),
    anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(15, 15),
    color: 'red'
    });
```

Comment: the contained pushpin counts  is set in the Microsoft.Maps.Clustering module  and I don't know how to replace it.

Comment: You can clear the text property by setting the text property to an empty string.  text: ''